# Selectively Adjusting the Vertical Starting Position of a New Chapter

Tags: pdftex, vertical-alignment, positioning, chapters, vertical

I would like to adjust the starting position of a chapter on a selective basis. For example,

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{Chapter 4}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

[image]

How may I, for example, lower the starting point (say 60pt), but keep the starting points of all the remaining chapters the same? I am hoping to have the flexibility of doing the same, later on, for other individual chapters as well, if more chapters were involved. I compile with `pdflatex`. Please no `AddtoHookNext`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titlesec` package provides two commands to format chapter titles (and other section commands) and spacing: `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` respectively.

```
\titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]{⟨format⟩}{⟨label⟩}{⟨sep⟩}{⟨before-code⟩}[⟨after-code⟩]


\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left margin>}{<vertical space before the title>}{<separation between title and text>}
```

You can then apply `\titlespacing` selectively, restricting its scope to the target chapter.

For this to work, `\titleformat` must be defined first. In the example we use the values used for the standard classes:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

See [titlesec documentation #9.2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)

Then it is possible to apply only for chapter 2  eg `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% definition of the standart classes
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{38pt}

\usepackage{showframe}% ONLY to show the margins

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \Large
    
    \chapter*{Chapter 1}
    \lipsum[3]
    
    {\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}
    \chapter*{Chapter 2}
    }
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \chapter*{Chapter 3}
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \chapter*{Chapter 4}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. But I am a little confused. Is `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{38pt}` part of the standard default? I did not see it in your explanation. Also, could you tell me exactly what the numbers 0, -20, and 20  represent in `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}`?  Many thanks.

Comment: @I. Yaromir The default is `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt} ` . The explanation of `\titlespacing` is at the beginning  of the answer `\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left margin>}{<vertical space before the title>}{<separation between title and text>}`

Comment: Thank you @SimonDispa

Answer (score 1):

You can add a trailing optional argument, default the normal 50pt, for stating the distance from the top margin (minus the `\topskip`).

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {50\p@}
  {\dimexpr\movechapter}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}
  {50\p@}
  {\dimexpr\movechapter}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\NewCommandCopy{\latexchapter}{\chapter} % may be \let\latexchapter\chapter
\newcommand{\movechapter}{}% initialize

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}mO{50pt}}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\movechapter}{#4}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\latexchapter*{#3}}{\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
  \endgroup
}
  

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{Chapter 2}[-\topskip]
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{Chapter 3}[20pt]
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{Chapter 4}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer.